# How to remove Gnome DE leftover Awesome WM in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, window-manager, awesome

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME, now I want to try Awesome WM but I don't know how to remove GNOME and install Awesome in the completely way. So I opened this issue and I hope someone can help me! Thanks.

This is what I want

[image: This is what I want :D]

Comment: Depending on your display manager (the one that lets you log into your GUI), maybe `gdm` or `lightdm`, you should be able to select the window manager when logging in. Do not remove `gnome`, as there are lots of libraries and applications related. And you should have a working fallback, if a different window manager does not work like expected.

Comment: Just tried it: `sudo apt install awesome awesome-extra`, then after logging out, I got a session selector in the top bar. Usually I'm using `lightdm`with `xfce4`, now I have `awesome` as additional selection. Maybe you have to modify the configuration of your display manager to have an entry like `sessions menu`.

Comment: Sorry, Could you give me a clearly way? I'm newbie. Thanks

Comment: How can I make awesome default ?

Comment: @Haniz you don't need to "make it default". Just select Awsome by clicking the icon in upper left corner of the greeter, and it will remember you choice for later logins.

Answer (score 0):

After installing `awesome` from apt-get set this in your `/usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=awesome
Comment=Highly configurable framework window manager
TryExec=awesome
Exec=awesome --no-argb
Type=Application
```

and log out of the session. Next time when you log in choose awesome instead of Ubuntu.